# OpenGL/GLSL in C working on desktop PC but not on laptop

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I am trying to simply render one quad currently in OpenGL with a texture of a player on it. It works perfectly on my PC, showing me the texture rendered on a quad. I have attached the texture image to this question in case you want to see (NB: it's a PNG). On my laptop however, it shows me a black screen. I know it is reading every single as black because I did a quick GLSL debug: `if (texture(u_Texture, Texcoord).xyz == vec3(.0f, .0f, .0f)) v_Texcoord = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` and it output a purely white quad, indicating to me that the debug code thinks every pixel is black. I loosely followed The Cherno's tutorial for the GLSL and OpenGL by the way. I changed the hertz and resolution of my PC screen to see if that was the problem, it wasn't. PS: the image file is found and the image is loaded properly on both my PC and laptop. If it wasn't, since the image is stored in the project path, it wouldn't work on my PC either.

Here are some assorted code snippets of my program (written in C):
**player initialization:**

```
void PlayerInit() {
    playerOrigScale.x /= (float)mode->width / 1000.0f;
    playerOrigScale.y /= (float)mode->height / 1000.0f;
    {
        float playerVerticiesInit[origPlrVertLen] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f,
        };
        float texCoordInit[8] = {
            .0f, .0f,
             1.0f, .0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
             .0f, 1.0f,
        };
        int i;
        int texCoordLen = lengthOf(texCoordInit);
        for (i = 0; i < texCoordLen; i++) {
            playerVerticies[i + ((i - i / 2) + 1 - (i % 2)) * 2] = texCoordInit[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < origPlrVertLen; i++) {
            origPlrPos[i] = playerVerticiesInit[i];
            playerVerticies[i + (i - (i % 2))] = origPlrPos[i] * (i % 2 == 0 ? playerOrigScale.x : playerOrigScale.y);
        }
    }
    verticiesLen = malloc(sizeof(byte));
    *verticiesLen = lengthOf(playerVerticies);
    unsigned int indicies[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };
    unsigned int vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    unsigned int vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(playerVerticies), playerVerticies, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    int* texAttrib = malloc(sizeof(int));
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4, (const void*)0);
    unsigned int ibo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indicies), indicies, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    ShaderProgramSource shaderSrc;
    {
        char* filepath = "Basic.shader";
        shaderSrc = ParseShader(filepath);
    }
    printf("vertex:\n%s\n", shaderSrc.vertexSource);
    printf("framgent:\n%s\n", shaderSrc.fragmentSource);
    shader = CreateShader(shaderSrc.vertexSource, shaderSrc.fragmentSource);
    glUseProgram(shader);
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_Color"), .1f, .6f, .9f, 1.0f);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_Texture"), 0);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, playerAnimator->frames[0][6]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 2));
    shouldDraw = true;
}
```

**main function snippet:**

```
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    playerAnimator = malloc(sizeof(Animator));
    playerAnimator->frames = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * 1);
    playerAnimator->animFrameNo[idle] = 7;
    *playerAnimator->frames = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * playerAnimator->animFrameNo[idle]);
    Init(playerAnimator);
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&pTime);
        char* save = ReadSaveFile("saves/save 1.txt", 500);
        printf("%s\n", save);
        free(save);
        printf("\nLoading save file took %f seconds. Keep in mind not printing save file will improve save access time to around .00125 seconds with lorem ipsum benchmark. This time will increase however with the encryption and the decryption which is yet to be implemented.\n", deltaTime());
    }
    glfwInit();
    monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
    mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_MAXIMIZED, true);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(mode->width, mode->height, title, fullScreen ? monitor : NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, NULL, 0, 0, mode->width, mode->height, mode->refreshRate);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    DWORD frameWaitTime = (DWORD)(1.0f / (float)mode->refreshRate * 1000.0f);
    glfwSwapInterval(vsyncCount);
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) ThrowError("your program is broken");
    PlayerInit();
    float fullScreenET = 0;
    //glUseProgram(0);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        if (!glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_FOCUSED)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
            Sleep(frameWaitTime * 10);
            continue;
        }
        if (pressing(GetKeyState(q)) && pressing(GetKeyState(leftControl))) break;
        //37, 39
        if (shouldDraw) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            shouldDraw = false;
        }
        //glUseProgram(shader);
        //glBindVertexArray(vao);
        //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        Update();
        printf("deltatime is %lf\n", DeltaTime());
        if (fullScreenET > .2f)
        {
            if (pressing(GetKeyState(key_return)) && pressing(GetKeyState(leftAlt))) {
                fullScreen = !fullScreen;
                glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, fullScreen ? monitor : NULL, 0, 0, mode->width, mode->height, mode->refreshRate);
                glfwSwapInterval(vsyncCount);
                fullScreenET = 0;
            }
        }
        else fullScreenET += deltaTime();
        //10000000
        if (shouldDraw) glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(playerVerticies), playerVerticies, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&pTime);
        //Sleep(frameWaitTime);
    }
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
```

**Basic.shader:**

```
#shader vertex
#version 430 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texcoord;
out vec2 Texcoord;
void main() {
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = position;
}
#shader fragment
#version 430 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 Texcoord;
out vec4 v_Texcoord;
uniform vec4 u_Color;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
void main() {
    v_Texcoord = texture(u_Texture, Texcoord);
}
//don't add empty line at end of file otherwise it breaks the shader interpretation
```

Comment: In the vertex shader, shouldn't `position` be a `vec2`, followed by using it as `vec4(position, 0.0F, 1.0F)`?

Comment: What does `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION)` and  `glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION)` tells you on your PC and Laptop? Based on your shader code, the OpenGL version has to be 4.3. Is that the case on both devices?

Comment: And you might want to set the context related hints (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE).

Comment: Hello Yun, in a response to your comment, no position should not be a vec2 and then be converted to a vec4 in the main function, because gl_Position is already a 4-component vector, assigning it to position which is also a vec4 will cut down on memory allocation because conversions create a new object with the converted value. To specify, the position works on both my laptop and PC, because I can render a purely white quad in the position it should be in on both devices.

Comment: So using `glVertexAttribPointer` to specify two attributes, each holding 2 floats, is correct with having a `vec4` and a `vec2` as input variables for the vertex shader? If so, then I wasn't aware of that functionality. Given the issue, there is probably UB somewhere, which may be in the data layout, causing the uv-coordinates to be read as zeroes.

Comment: Yes I believe passing two floats into the function is fine, as the position vertices are working fine in both shaders, it is only the output of color that is not working.

Comment: Yes Erdal, the version is ```4.6.13560 Compatibility Profile Context 26.20.11034.1006``` on my  PC and ```4.6.0 - Build 30.0.101.3111``` on laptop.

Comment: See https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_hints_values (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR = 1, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR = 0), Set the hints before context creation.

Comment: I set the GLFW hints as stated and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Are the texture coordinates fine when you draw them as color? glGenerateMipmaps has to be called after glTexImage2D, but that's alnot your current problem since you're not using mipmaps.

Comment: Hi BDL, yes i can render a white quad on the screen in either scenario, the only difference is on my laptop it reads every pixel in the texture as black

Comment: What I meant is v_Texcoord = vec4(Texcoord.x, Texcoord.y, 0, 1). Do you see a red/green color gradient? I just noticed that is very atypical to specify explicit locations for the inputs of a fragment shader, so you could also try removing those.

Comment: I specify the locations so that I don't have to find them with a string because it is faster to find them with a pre-determined location.

Comment: _"Yes I believe passing two floats into the function is fine, as the position vertices are working fine in both shaders, it is only the output of color that is not working."_ This cannot be concluded like this. It may very well be the case that the vertex shader is reading uninitialized data, or part of the texture coordinates, for the last two floats of `position` which somehow (implementation defined) still makes the positions work but not the texcoords. The arguments to `glVertexAttribPointer` and the input variables to the vertex shader just don't match.

Comment: _"I specify the locations so that I don't have to find them with a string because it is faster to find them with a pre-determined location."_ This may hold for the vertex shader, but not for the inputs of the fragment shader.

Comment: @nugget: I talked about the locations in the **fragment** shader. Those are never searched by your program. But if the output locations of the vertex shader and the input locations of the fragment shader don't match, anything can happen. Usually,  the glsl compiler determines match by name, unless you specify locations, than it takes those. If you mix (no explicit output locations in vert, but input locations in frag), then again anything can happen.

Comment: @Yun: Passing less floats to the function than required by the shader is fine. The standard mandates that missing values will be filled by OpenGL with 0 for [x,y,z] and with 1 for [w]. This is covered by the [OpenGL 4.6 spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) in section 10.3.5

Comment: @Yun what am I missing in my vertex data? I thought I filled it in properly.
PS: if you are referring to the ```playerVerticiesInit``` or ```texCoordInit```, they aren't actually the verticies that are used by OpenGL, they are just a template I use to get to my actual verticies, which are stored in ```playerVerticies```

Comment: @BDL update: v_Texcoord = vec4(Texcoord.x, Texcoord.y, 0, 1) does not work on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks BLT it was the specification of the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the manual specification of the layout in my fragment shader. Thank you so much Erdal Küçük and BDL and everyone else that helped. Weird though that there is some sort of different setting on my PC to my laptop. It could be because the version on my PC was very slightly newer.

Comment: The automatic assignment of locations for inputs and outputs is implementation dependent. Different drivers might implement it differently

Comment: Thanks for the help, by the way is there a better way to move the thing than iterating through all of the verticies increasing their position one by one?

Comment: @BDL is there a faster way for O(1) time complexity of moving the quad without iterating through all x position verticies